# Parse complex, nested, prefixed XML nodes in PHP using XMLReader

Tags: php, xml, xmlreader

For days I have been searching, reading and trying to parse my XML files, but so far no luck. This is a sample of one of my XML files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/rss/styles/shared_xsl_stylesheet_v2.xml"?>
<rss version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title>All XBRL Data Submitted to the SEC for 2014-10</title>
        <link>http://www.sec.gov/spotlight/xbrl/filings-and-feeds.shtml</link>
        <atom:link href="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-2014-10.xml" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"/>
        <description>This is a list all of the filings containing XBRL for 2014-10</description>
        <language>en-us</language>
        <pubDate>Mon, 27 Oct 2014 00:00:00 EDT</pubDate>
        <lastBuildDate>Mon, 27 Oct 2014 00:00:00 EDT</lastBuildDate>
        <item>
            <title>Bling Marketing, Inc. (0001593549) (Filer)</title>
            <link>http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/0001014897-14-000441-index.htm</link>
            <guid>http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/0001014897-14-000441-xbrl.zip</guid>
            <enclosure url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/0001014897-14-000441-xbrl.zip" length="30761" type="application/zip" />
            <description>10-Q</description>
            <pubDate>Mon, 27 Oct 2014 17:25:14 EDT</pubDate>
            <edgar:xbrlFiling xmlns:edgar="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar">
                <edgar:companyName>Bling Marketing, Inc.</edgar:companyName>
                <edgar:formType>10-Q</edgar:formType>
                <edgar:filingDate>10/27/2014</edgar:filingDate>
                <edgar:cikNumber>0001593549</edgar:cikNumber>
                <edgar:accessionNumber>0001014897-14-000441</edgar:accessionNumber>
                <edgar:fileNumber>333-192997</edgar:fileNumber>
                <edgar:acceptanceDatetime>20141027172514</edgar:acceptanceDatetime>
                <edgar:period>20140930</edgar:period>
                <edgar:assistantDirector>2</edgar:assistantDirector>
                <edgar:assignedSic>5094</edgar:assignedSic>
                <edgar:fiscalYearEnd>1231</edgar:fiscalYearEnd>
                <edgar:xbrlFiles>
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="1" edgar:file="bling10q3q14v2.htm" edgar:type="10-Q" edgar:size="174242" edgar:description="FORM 10-Q" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/bling10q3q14v2.htm" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="2" edgar:file="bling10q3q14ex31.htm" edgar:type="EX-31" edgar:size="5481" edgar:description="EXHIBIT 31" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/bling10q3q14ex31.htm" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="3" edgar:file="bling10q3q14ex32.htm" edgar:type="EX-32" edgar:size="1827" edgar:description="EXHIBIT 32" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/bling10q3q14ex32.htm" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="4" edgar:file="blmi-20140930.xml" edgar:type="EX-101.INS" edgar:size="149179" edgar:description="XBRL INSTANCE DOCUMENT" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/blmi-20140930.xml" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="5" edgar:file="blmi-20140930.xsd" edgar:type="EX-101.SCH" edgar:size="28373" edgar:description="XBRL TAXONOMY EXTENSION SCHEMA DOCUMENT" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/blmi-20140930.xsd" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="6" edgar:file="blmi-20140930_cal.xml" edgar:type="EX-101.CAL" edgar:size="7021" edgar:description="XBRL TAXONOMY EXTENSION CALCULATION LINKBASE DOCUMENT" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/blmi-20140930_cal.xml" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="7" edgar:file="blmi-20140930_def.xml" edgar:type="EX-101.DEF" edgar:size="17205" edgar:description="XBRL TAXONOMY EXTENSION DEFINITION LINKBASE DOCUMENT" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/blmi-20140930_def.xml" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="8" edgar:file="blmi-20140930_lab.xml" edgar:type="EX-101.LAB" edgar:size="74477" edgar:description="XBRL TAXONOMY EXTENSION LABEL LINKBASE DOCUMENT" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/blmi-20140930_lab.xml" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="9" edgar:file="blmi-20140930_pre.xml" edgar:type="EX-101.PRE" edgar:size="67806" edgar:description="XBRL TAXONOMY EXTENSION PRESENTATION LINKBASE DOCUMENT" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/blmi-20140930_pre.xml" />
                </edgar:xbrlFiles>
            </edgar:xbrlFiling>
        </item>
        <item>
            <title>Primco Management Inc. (0001516522) (Filer)</title>
            <link>http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/0001014897-14-000414-index.htm</link>
            <guid>http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/0001014897-14-000414-xbrl.zip</guid>
            <enclosure url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/0001014897-14-000414-xbrl.zip" length="80939" type="application/zip" />
            <description>10-K/A</description>
            <pubDate>Tue, 30 Sep 2014 17:41:38 EDT</pubDate>
            <edgar:xbrlFiling xmlns:edgar="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar">
                <edgar:companyName>Primco Management Inc.</edgar:companyName>
                <edgar:formType>10-K/A</edgar:formType>
                <edgar:filingDate>10/01/2014</edgar:filingDate>
                <edgar:cikNumber>0001516522</edgar:cikNumber>
                <edgar:accessionNumber>0001014897-14-000414</edgar:accessionNumber>
                <edgar:fileNumber>000-54930</edgar:fileNumber>
                <edgar:acceptanceDatetime>20140930174138</edgar:acceptanceDatetime>
                <edgar:period>20131231</edgar:period>
                <edgar:assistantDirector>8</edgar:assistantDirector>
                <edgar:assignedSic>6531</edgar:assignedSic>
                <edgar:fiscalYearEnd>1231</edgar:fiscalYearEnd>
                <edgar:xbrlFiles>
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="1" edgar:file="primco10k13am2v2.htm" edgar:type="10-K/A" edgar:size="482147" edgar:description="FORM 10-K/A" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/primco10k13am2v2.htm" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="2" edgar:file="primco10k13ex31.htm" edgar:type="EX-31" edgar:size="10412" edgar:description="EXHIBIT 31" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/primco10k13ex31.htm" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="3" edgar:file="primco10k13ex32.htm" edgar:type="EX-32" edgar:size="3121" edgar:description="EXHIBIT 32" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/primco10k13ex32.htm" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="4" edgar:file="pmcm-20131231.xml" edgar:type="EX-101.INS" edgar:size="891933" edgar:description="XBRL INSTANCE DOCUMENT" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/pmcm-20131231.xml" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="5" edgar:file="pmcm-20131231.xsd" edgar:type="EX-101.SCH" edgar:size="54127" edgar:description="XBRL TAXONOMY EXTENSION SCHEMA DOCUMENT" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/pmcm-20131231.xsd" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="6" edgar:file="pmcm-20131231_cal.xml" edgar:type="EX-101.CAL" edgar:size="12529" edgar:description="XBRL TAXONOMY EXTENSION CALCULATION LINKBASE DOCUMENT" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/pmcm-20131231_cal.xml" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="7" edgar:file="pmcm-20131231_def.xml" edgar:type="EX-101.DEF" edgar:size="77249" edgar:description="XBRL TAXONOMY EXTENSION DEFINITION LINKBASE DOCUMENT" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/pmcm-20131231_def.xml" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="8" edgar:file="pmcm-20131231_lab.xml" edgar:type="EX-101.LAB" edgar:size="146832" edgar:description="XBRL TAXONOMY EXTENSION LABEL LINKBASE DOCUMENT" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/pmcm-20131231_lab.xml" />
                    <edgar:xbrlFile edgar:sequence="9" edgar:file="pmcm-20131231_pre.xml" edgar:type="EX-101.PRE" edgar:size="131110" edgar:description="XBRL TAXONOMY EXTENSION PRESENTATION LINKBASE DOCUMENT" edgar:url="http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/pmcm-20131231_pre.xml" />
                </edgar:xbrlFiles>
            </edgar:xbrlFiling>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

The XML files are around 30MB, which should be fine to parse with simpleXML, but the problem lies in the fact that simpleXML is unable to handle tags like `<edgar:formType>`. Guess they're not "simple" enough ;-)

Therefore I tried parsing with XMLReader, which *is* able to parse those tags. This works for example:

```
// Initialize XMLReader and DOMdocument
$reader = new XMLReader();
$reader->open("file.xml");

$storage = array();

// Move to the first <item> node
while ($reader->read() && $reader->name !== "item");

// Loop through the entire instance document
while ( $reader->read() ) {

    // Ensure that nodeType is an Element and not an Attribute or Text
    if($reader->nodeType == XMLReader::ELEMENT) {
        // Extract and store filing info in $storage array
        switch ($reader->localName) {
          case "formType":
            $reader->read();
            $storage["formType"] = $reader->value;
            break;
          case "cikNumber":
            $reader->read();
            $storage["cik"] = $reader->value;
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }       
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($storage); echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

The `print_r` returns a lot of empty and duplicate results though..

I want to loop through each `<item>`and store the following data points using MySQLi:

- `<guid>`
- `<edgar:companyName>`
- `<edgar:formType>`
- `<edgar:filingDate>`
- `<edgar:cikNumber>`
- `<edgar:accessionNumber>`
- `<edgar:period>`
- `<edgar:fiscalYearEnd>`
- `edgar:url` attribute of`<edgar:xbrlFile>` node if the attribute `edgar:description` = "XBRL INSTANCE DOCUMENT"

I feel like I'm close, since I'm already able to extract values based on `localName` (which targets the part after `edgar:`), but I don't know how to access the attributes and how to store the data per `<item>` in my database.

Would greatly appreciate some help here, since none of the examples I found online showed how to process these prefixed XML tags. Thanks in advance!

Nick

Comment: try item->children('edgar', true)->...  to parse them.  I think that will allow you to use simplexml

Comment: Wow Jim, you are a hero! So, so simple... Totally missed that method. Wasted several days on this haha, thanks for your reply! I should be able to figure out the rest myself.

Comment: @kregus for future reference, the "prefix" on the tag is called a namespace--it can be surprisingly difficult to find documentation on things if you don't know the correct terminology! :^)

Comment: @kregus I out it as an answer, if you could accept it that would be great.  Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: @i alarmed alien: So true! I came across the word "namespace" a couple of times but did not connect the dots until you guys saved the day, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try item->children('edgar', true)->... to parse them. I think that will allow you to use simplexml.  The edgar: is called namespacing, and is used quite a bit with xml files.  I had the same issue a while back and this fixed it for me,

Answer (score 0):

Since you were originally trying to do this with SimpleXML, here is a solution for parsing the XML using simpleXML, and particularly its [xpath method](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php), which gives you a very easy, handy way to select nodes in an XML document. Most of the

```
# you will probably be loading the XML from a file here rather than a string...
$sxe = simplexml_load_string( $xml );

# this xpath looks for "item" elements that are under the "channel" element    
foreach ($sxe->xpath("channel/item") as $i) {

    # for this example, I'll just store the data and print it after parsing each item
    $data = array();

    # cast the node as a string
    $data['guid'] = (string)$i->guid;

    # register the URI associated with the 'edgar' namespace
    # tags can be referred to using "e:tagName" from now on
    $i->registerXPathNamespace("e", "http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar");

    foreach ( array("companyName", "formType", "filingDate", "cikNumber",
        "accessionNumber", "period", "fiscalYearEnd") as $tag) {
        # create the xpath dynamically from the tag name. All tags are under the "item"
        # node ($i) under the parent edgar:xbrlFiling (i.e. e:xbrlFiling)
        $data[ $tag ] = (string)$i->xpath("e:xbrlFiling/e:$tag")[0];
    }

    # this searches for e:xbrlFile nodes with description "XBRL INSTANCE DOCUMENT"
    # the final /@e:url returns the e:url attribute, rather than the node itself 
    foreach ($i->xpath(
  "e:xbrlFiling/e:xbrlFiles/e:xbrlFile[@e:description='XBRL INSTANCE DOCUMENT']/@e:url"
                           ) as $url) {
        # you may want to use an array here if there are several such URLs
        $data['url'] = (string)$url;
    }
    print_r($data);
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [guid] => http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/0001014897-14-000441-xbrl.zip
    [companyName] => Bling Marketing, Inc.
    [formType] => 10-Q
    [filingDate] => 10/27/2014
    [cikNumber] => 0001593549
    [accessionNumber] => 0001014897-14-000441
    [period] => 20140930
    [fiscalYearEnd] => 1231
    [url] => http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1593549/000101489714000441/blmi-20140930.xml
)
Array
(
    [guid] => http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/0001014897-14-000414-xbrl.zip
    [companyName] => Primco Management Inc.
    [formType] => 10-K/A
    [filingDate] => 10/01/2014
    [cikNumber] => 0001516522
    [accessionNumber] => 0001014897-14-000414
    [period] => 20131231
    [fiscalYearEnd] => 1231
    [url] => http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1516522/000101489714000414/pmcm-20131231.xml
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I did explore XPath as an alternative option, but could not figure out the correct syntax for extracting the nodes I needed. It might help some others who stumble upon this thread though, so thank!

Comment: I find it much easier than faffing around with `node->children` -- you can just specify the nodes you want directly, and it's very powerful if you want to get nodes with a specific attribute or value.